# Error while installing fingerprints module in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to install fingerprints module in python but I get this error.

```
RuntimeError:
Please set the ICU_VERSION environment variable to the version of
ICU you have installed.
```

I tried the command

```
pip install fingerprints
```

total description of error is show below.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\aravind emmadishetty\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ARAVIN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d4ljgy00\\pyicu\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ARAVIN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d4ljgy00\\pyicu\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
     cwd: C:\Users\ARAVIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d4ljgy00\pyicu\
Complete output (53 lines):
(running 'icu-config --version')
(running 'pkg-config --modversion icu-i18n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ARAVIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d4ljgy00\pyicu\setup.py", line 62, in <module>
    ICU_VERSION = os.environ['ICU_VERSION']
  File "c:\users\aravind emmadishetty\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'ICU_VERSION'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ARAVIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d4ljgy00\pyicu\setup.py", line 65, in <module>
    ICU_VERSION = check_output(('icu-config', '--version')).strip()
  File "C:\Users\ARAVIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d4ljgy00\pyicu\setup.py", line 18, in check_output
    return subprocess_check_output(popenargs)
  File "c:\users\aravind emmadishetty\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "c:\users\aravind emmadishetty\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "c:\users\aravind emmadishetty\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "c:\users\aravind emmadishetty\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ARAVIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d4ljgy00\pyicu\setup.py", line 68, in <module>
    ICU_VERSION = check_output(('pkg-config', '--modversion', 'icu-i18n')).strip()
  File "C:\Users\ARAVIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d4ljgy00\pyicu\setup.py", line 18, in check_output
    return subprocess_check_output(popenargs)
  File "c:\users\aravind emmadishetty\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "c:\users\aravind emmadishetty\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "c:\users\aravind emmadishetty\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "c:\users\aravind emmadishetty\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ARAVIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d4ljgy00\pyicu\setup.py", line 73, in <module>
    ''')
RuntimeError:
Please set the ICU_VERSION environment variable to the version of
ICU you have installed.

----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error yesterday while trying to install a different package from github. I got around it by downloading the zip file and installing it manually, without pip.

Before doing that you may want to try 'pip3 install git+< copy_GitHub_web_URL_here >'. You can get that from their GitHub page: https://github.com/alephdata/fingerprints .

I have been having many egg_info errors over the past few months so the other suggestions (that have never worked for me but may be worth a shot as they work for some people) are: updating pip and setuptools, and to try using pip3 install or sudo pip3 install instead of just pip install.

I hope this helps in some way. If not, I hope that someone with more knowledge on the subject can help as I am still very new at this.

Comment: It didn't worked. I am using windows 10. I think it may not work for windows10?

Comment: It looks like you may not have all of the dependancies. You may have to install PyICU. Here is a link describing a similar problem https://github.com/chillerno1/noted/issues/1

Comment: Recently I have tried and installed it with no effort using pip. May be it is because I have installed  anaconda before or may be the problem is fixed by developers.